# C++ variadic callback

Tags: c++, callback, variadic-templates, variadic

Variadic functions in C++ allow the user to call a function with an arbitrary number of arguments. As an example, sscanf takes as an input a string to be parsed, a format string, and a set of parameters that will take the values of the parsed items.
What if I wanted to make this paradigm asynchronous? I need to parse some data, extracting a variable number of parameters from some bytes. The parameters that need to be extracted are specified in a format string as in sscanf. I would like my function to be called like this:

```
function <void (int, int, int)> myfunc = [=] (int a, int b, int c)
{
    // Do something here!
};

asyncsscanf(my_bytes, "iii", myfunc);
```

asyncsscanf should do the needed processing and when completed I would like it to call myfunc with the correct arguments specified in the format string.
Is it possible to do such a thing?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need `"iii"` when you have the raw types right there?

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your point. Could you explain that more in depth?

Comment: You pass `"iii"` to your function.  Why?  `myfunc` is of type `function<void(int,int,int)>` -- why pass a string with a duplicate of that information?  Why use runtime data?

Comment: Thanks! I got your point. I don't even know a way to do it with that duplicate information! Could you give me an hint on how you would do that?

Comment: Can you write `int read_int(byte*&)`?  Or something equivalent?  (synchronous read from bytes to one value, updates the input to be after the read data, in this case).  There is lots of boiler plate in that and lots of decisions, and I think mostly unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how to do it with your approach.

First, there is no good type for third parameter of asyncscanf function. Only acceptable in asyncscanf body would be void(...) (function taking unlimited number of arguments and returns nothing), but then argument you pass to asyncscanf as third should be of that type which is probably not acceptable.

Second, you have to do dispaching of my_bytes according to format ("iii" in example). This could be done if you have finite number of different format strings (then you can 'switch' over all possible formats). But in general case I suppose it cannot be done.

But because you mark your question with 'variadic-templates' I assume that you are using C++11/14.
Maybe you would like to make format argument of asyncscanf a template argument which would be more readable (I assume that format is always known in compilation time). Below snippet of solution.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// template parsing function, remaining_bytes parameter should contain pointer to not parsed part
// of my_bytes
template <typename return_type> return_type parse(const char *my_bytes, const char *&remaining_bytes);

// specialization of parsing function for desired types, fake implementation
template <> int parse<int>(const char *my_bytes, const char *&remaining_bytes) {
    remaining_bytes = my_bytes;
    return 0;
}

// specialization of parsing function for desired types, fake implementation
template <> long parse<long>(const char *my_bytes, const char *&remaining_bytes) {
    remaining_bytes = my_bytes;
    return 1;
}

// declare helper template for general case
template <typename to_be_parsed_tuple, typename parsed_tuple>
struct asyncscanf_helper;

// all params parsed case
template <typename... parsed_params>
struct asyncscanf_helper<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<parsed_params...>> {
    void operator()(const char *, std::function<void(parsed_params...)> fun, parsed_params... params) {
        fun(params...);
    }
};

// some params to be parsed case
template <typename first_param_to_be_parsed, typename...to_be_parsed_params, typename... parsed_params>
struct asyncscanf_helper<std::tuple<first_param_to_be_parsed, to_be_parsed_params...>, std::tuple<parsed_params...>> {
    void operator()(const char *my_bytes, std::function<void(parsed_params..., first_param_to_be_parsed, to_be_parsed_params...)> fun, parsed_params... params) {
        const char *remaining_bytes = 0;
        first_param_to_be_parsed p1 = parse<first_param_to_be_parsed>(my_bytes, remaining_bytes);
        asyncscanf_helper<std::tuple<to_be_parsed_params...>, std::tuple<parsed_params..., first_param_to_be_parsed>>()(remaining_bytes, fun, params..., p1);
    }
};

template <typename... params>
void asyncscanf(const char *my_bytes, void function(params...)) {
    asyncscanf_helper<std::tuple<params...>, std::tuple<>>()(my_bytes, function);
}

void test_fun(int a, int b, int c) {
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << std::endl;
}

void test_fun2(int a, long b, int c) {
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    asyncscanf("1 2 3", test_fun);
    asyncscanf("1 2 3", test_fun2);
}
```

Notes about code:

- idea is that we have two parameter packs: one for not parsed yet parameters and one for already parsed parameters and pass parameters one by one from first pack to second; when all parameters are parsed simply call the function
- if you forget to specialize parse function for type needed by function passed as third argument to asyncscanf compiler will tell you about that.
- I had to use template struct asyncscanf_helper and tuples instead of simple function template  asyncscanf_helper because of problems with usage of two parameter packs in one template function.
- I have used std::function in asyncscanf_helper because it is more general and you could use e.g. lambdas as your arguments, but at the moment I leave standard function in asyncscanf as parameter type because otherwise its second argument must be explicitly cast to std::function with appropriate signature or template parameters must be stated explicitly.
- Because of fake implementation of parse function specializations you will not see expected results if you run code but because parsing was not part of your question I left it mocked.

Comment: A slight improvement would be to enable ADL for `parse` by replacing the `template` type with a deducible pointer-to-T.  You could either write there (initialized or not), or ignore it and return the value.